# Python substitute elements inside a list

Tags: python, list, substitution

I have the following code that is filtering and printing a list. The final output is json that is in the form of name.example.com. I want to substitute that with name.sub.example.com but I'm having a hard time actually doing that. filterIP is a working bit of code that removes elements entirely and I have been trying to re-use that bit to also modify elements, it doesn't have to be handled this way.

```
def filterIP(fullList):
    regexIP = re.compile(r'\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}$')
    return filter(lambda i: not regexIP.search(i), fullList)

def filterSub(fullList2):
    regexSub = re.compile(r'example\.com, sub.example.com')
    return filter(lambda i: regexSub.search(i), fullList2)

groups = {key : filterSub(filterIP(list(set(items)))) for (key, items) in groups.iteritems() }

print(self.json_format_dict(groups, pretty=True))
```

This is what I get without filterSub

```
"type_1": [
    "server1.example.com",
    "server2.example.com"
],
```

This is what I get with filterSub

```
"type_1": [],
```

This is what I'm trying to get

```
"type_1": [
    "server1.sub.example.com",
    "server2.sub.example.com"
],
```

Comment: re.sub expects a string not a list ... convieniently enough json is a string ... so if you pass it in after making it into json it might just work as is

Comment: You need to get your regex right. Probably add wildcard before for a match. I'd tweak the regex in a console until it's right. Maybe add regex tag to question

Comment: Is there a way specifically to recompile lists the way I'm looking to do? Everything I find is for string manipulation. I'll fiddle around with modifying after it's printed to json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement:

```
regexSub = re.compile(r'example\.com, sub.example.com')
```

doesn't do what you think it does.  It creates a compiled regular expression that matches the string "example.com" followed by a comma, a space, the string "sub", an arbitrary character, the string "example", an arbitrary character, and the string "com".  It does *not* create any sort of substitution.

Instead, you want to write something like this, using the `re.sub` function to perform the substitution and using `map` to apply it:

```
def filterSub(fullList2):
    regexSub = re.compile(r'example\.com')
    return map(lambda i: re.sub(regexSub, "sub.example.com", i),
               filter(lambda i: re.search(regexSub, i), fullList2))
```

Comment: or you can `map` `regexSub.sub`

Answer (score 0):

If the examples are all truly as simple as those you listed, a regex is probably overkill.  A simple solution would be to use string `.split` and `.join`.  This would likely give better performance.

First split the url at the first period:

```
url = 'server1.example.com'
split_url = url.split('.', 1)  
# ['server1', 'example.com']
```

Then you can use the sub to rejoin the url:

```
subbed_url = '.sub.'.join(split_url)
# 'server1.sub.example.com'
```

Of course you can do the split and the join at the same time

```
'.sub.'.join(url.split('.', 1))
```

Or create a simple function:
    def sub_url(url):
        return '.sub.'.join(url.split('.', 1))

To apply this to the list you can take several approaches.

A list comprehension:

```
subbed_list = [sub_url(url)
               for url in url_list]
```

Map it:

```
subbed_list = map(sub_url, url_list)
```

Or my favorite, a generator:

```
gen_subbed = (sub_url(url)
               for url in url_list)
```

The last looks like a list comprehension but gives the added benefit that you don't rebuild the entire list.  It processes the elements one item at a time as the generator is iterated through.  If you decide you do need the list later you can simply convert it to a list as follows:

```
subbed_list = list(gen_subbed)
```